# NVReportExt.dll: System Exceptions: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

I am getting below error in VUGEN

```
Error: Exception was raised when calling event-notify Vuser function in extension NVReportExt.dll: System Exceptions: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
```

What could be the reason for this?

I have checked the paraameter files used, those are okay

Comment: Could you disable NV in VuGen Options>Scripting>Replay and see if it is reproduced?

Answer (score 1):

By Disabling NV insights Report from Vugen>>Tools>>Options>>Replay>>NV insightreport display

Works perfectly fine.